# map() model output to a dataframe

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

I've been using `map()` to calculate and extract certain  statistics from multiple `lm()` models.

To give a reproducible example, using the mtcars dataset, I start with an input vector of formulae to be estimated using `lm()` models:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- mtcars
input_char <- c("mpg ~ disp",
                "mpg ~ disp + hp")
input_formula <- map(input_char, formula)
```

I've then got a function that calculates and extracts the relevant statistics for each model. For simplicity and reproducibility, here's a simplified function that just extracts the R-squared of the model.

```
get_rsquared <- function(a_formula) {
  model1 <- lm(a_formula, data = df)
  rsquared <- summary(model1)$r.squared
  c(model = a_formula, rsquared = rsquared)
}
```

I've then used `map` to iterate through the formulae and extract the R-squared from each model.

```
models <- map(input_formula, get_rsquared)
models
```

which gives the output:

```
[[1]]
[[1]]$model
mpg ~ disp
<environment: 0x7f98987f4000>

[[1]]$rsquared
[1] 0.7183433


[[2]]
[[2]]$model
mpg ~ disp + hp
<environment: 0x7f98987f4000>

[[2]]$rsquared
[1] 0.7482402
```

My question is regarding the output being a list.

Is there a simple way to make the output a dataframe?

My desired output is:

```
#>             model  rsquared
#> 1      mpg ~ disp 0.7183433
#> 2 mpg ~ disp + hp 0.7482402
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep the formulas as character strings and use `as.formula()` as part of the the `get_rsquared()` function as it's easier to work with them as character strings than formula objects.

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

df <- mtcars
input_char <- c("mpg ~ disp",
                "mpg ~ disp + hp")

get_rsquared <- function(a_formula) {
  model1 <- lm(as.formula(a_formula), data = df)
  rsquared <- summary(model1)$r.squared
  list(model = a_formula, rsquared = rsquared)
}

map_df(input_char, get_rsquared)

# A tibble: 2 x 2
  model           rsquared
  <chr>              <dbl>
1 mpg ~ disp         0.718
2 mpg ~ disp + hp    0.748
```

Comment: Just in case anyone is reading this in the future, the reason `map_df` hadn't previously worked for me was identified by @h-1: because my `input_char` vector got converted to a vector of formulae, it did not feed nicely into `map_df`, whereas a vector of char works very well, as shown by @h-1's elegant solution.

Comment: I found the code example you gave to be very helpful. Would you recommend storing formulae as a vector of `char` and then using `as.formula()` to convert when necessary? (Seeing as it's not as easy to convert formula to char?